# How to attach variables of one observation to another within the same dataset in R

Tags: r, dataframe

My problem is as follows:

Suppose that I have a dataset of person-years with information on marital status (cStatus), race, year, spouse id (pID) and city of residence:

```
data<-data.frame(cbind(c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5),rep(3,5),rep(4,5),rep(5,5)),c(rep(c(1,2,3,4,5),5)),c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,3,3,NA,NA,NA,2,2,7,6,6,6,6,6,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0),c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1),c(rep(1,5),rep(1,2),rep(2,3),rep(2,4),1,rep(1,5),rep(1,5))))
names(data)<- c("id","year","pID","cStatus","race","city")

> head(data)  
id year pID cStatus race city
 1    1    NA       0    1    1
 1    2    NA       0    1    1
 1    3    NA       0    1    1
 1    4    NA       0    1    1
 1    5    NA       0    1    1
 2    1    NA       0    1    1
```

I want to create a variable for spouse's race (pRace) for each observation. I am trying to do it for a given observation "A" by searching in the dataset for other observation "B" which "id" has the same value as "pID" of  observation "A" and assigning "B"s "race" to "A"s pRace.

I thought about looping:

```
for(i in unique(data$id)){
  data[data$id==i,]$pRace <-ifelse(data[data$id==i,]$cStatus==1,data[data$id==data[data$id==i,]$pID,]$race,NA)
}
```

This, besides being very ugly, yields:

```
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, data$id == i, , value = list(id = c(1,  :
  provided 8 variables to replace 7 variables
```

Is there any way of doing it right? Am I in the right way by trying to use loops?

Comment: It sounds like you just need to use `merge`.

Comment: @joran Andy suggested it as an answer down there. It works, but I have cases in which people changed partners and I would like to have the race of a partner in a given year.

Comment: You can merge on more than one variable. `merge` serves roughly the same functionality as SQL joins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# create a dataframe that has unique entries for each person and their race
spouses <- unique(data[c("id", "race")])
names(spouses) <- c("pID", "pRace")

# merge race via spouse id
data <- merge(data, spouses, by="pID", all.x=TRUE)
```

Which gives:

```
> data
   pID id year cStatus race city pRace
1    2  3    4       1    0    2     1
2    2  3    3       1    0    2     1
3    3  2    4       1    1    2     0
4    3  2    3       1    1    2     0
5    6  4    2       1    0    1    NA
6    6  4    1       1    0    1    NA
7    6  4    3       1    0    1    NA
8    6  4    5       1    0    1    NA
9    6  4    4       1    0    1    NA
10   7  3    5       1    0    1    NA
11  NA  1    1       0    1    1    NA
12  NA  1    2       0    1    1    NA
[...]
```

Notice you get NA's where either the `pID` doesn't itself exist in the data (no corresponding `id`) or where there is no spouse.

If you wanted to account for changing spouses over years, just add years to both the helper dataframe as well as the `merge` arguments. Like @joran points out, `merge` can accept multiple columns to merge on, similar to SQL.

```
# create a dataframe that has unique entries for each person and their race
spouses.yearly <- unique(data[c("id", "year", "race")])
names(spouses.yearly) <- c("pID", "pRace")

# merge race via spouse id
data <- merge(data, spouses.yearly, by=c("pID", "year"), all.x=TRUE)
```